# Swift: resize an image is a solution?

Tags: ios, swift

I am analyzing the images captured by the camera, I am going through each pixel by pixel and storing the rgb value of each pixel in an dictionary, obviously it's taking a lot of time. Can I scale down an image without loosing the percentage of color ratio in the image...

Example: Original image has RGB color and count as

```
                     Color           count
                   [0xF0F0F0]         100
                   [0xB0B0B0]          50
                   [0x909090]          20
```

Then after scaling the image by half the color count in  scaled image is like this:

```
                     Color           count
                   [0xF0F0F0]          50
                   [0xB0B0B0]          25
                   [0x909090]          10
```

So 2 questions:
 1. Is this doable in Swift?
 2. If yes, then how do I scale an image in swift

Comment: What I recommend instead of eliminating colors, is resize it

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? Do you just want to resize the image?

Comment: it sounds like OP wants a count of each colour value in an image, but this takes a long time to process, so is there a way to resize the image and get the same ratio of counts of each colour (seems like the ratio is more important than the actual number of instances of a colour)

Comment: Also this type of processes should run on the graphic card and no on the CPU

Comment: Fonix is correct in understanding my question, I will look at other answers as well !

Answer (score 0):

This is my code for resizing a image taken by the camera, after this process I send it to our servers. I recommend it to resize it instead of eliminating colors.

Also if you don't want to resize it, you can't convert the image to JPEG and assign a quality.

Use `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` instead of `UIImagePNGRepresentation`

```
if let img = value as? UIImage {

                var newWidth = 0
                var newHeight = 0
                var sizeLimit = 700 //in px

                let originalWidth = Int(img.size.width)
                let originalHeight = Int(img.size.height)

                //Get new size with max w/h = 700
                if originalWidth > originalHeight {
                    //Max width
                    newWidth = sizeLimit
                    newHeight = (originalHeight*sizeLimit)/originalWidth
                }else{
                    newWidth = (originalWidth*sizeLimit)/originalHeight
                    newHeight = sizeLimit
                }

                let newSize = CGSizeMake(CGFloat(newWidth), CGFloat(newHeight))
                UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(newSize)
                img.drawInRect(CGRectMake(0, 0, CGFloat(newWidth), CGFloat(newHeight)))
                let newImg = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
                UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

                //This is a UIIMAGE
                let imageData:UIImage = UIImagePNGRepresentation(newImg)
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

Scaling down an image will definitely lose some pixels.

To scale an image in Swift:

```
var scaledImage // your scaled-down image
var origImage   // your original image

let itemSize = CGSizeMake(origImage.size.width/2, origImage.size.height/2)
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(itemSize, false, UIScreen.mainScreen().scale)
let imageRect = CGRectMake(0.0, 0.0, itemSize.width, itemSize.height)
origImage.drawInRect(imageRect)
scaledImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
```

Answer (score 0):

i would say this probably isnt possible, because resizing the image would change the value of the actual colours so it would give you different results.

but maybe you can look into speeding it up using the full sized image. Look into maybe using [metal](https://developer.apple.com/metal/) for GPU accelerated calculations

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Is this doable in Swift?

Sure

> 2. If yes, then how do I scale an image in swift

If you don't mind low level functions, since this is something you want to have done fast and on the CPU, not GPU, you might want to look at the Accelerate framework and [vImage_scale](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Performance/Reference/vImage_geometric/index.html#//apple_ref/c/func/vImageScale_ARGB8888) in particular. It provides direct access to the RGB data in memory as well.

When I did something similar in the past, I noticed that the scaling actually cuts off some colors and does not give accurate representation of the original. Unfortunately, I don't have the examples to show anymore, but I'd suggest that you try this technique with different scaling ratio to see if it gives satisfactory data in your case.

Answer (score 0):

```
func scaleAndRotateImage(image: UIImage, MaxResolution iIntMaxResolution: Int) -> UIImage {
        let kMaxResolution = iIntMaxResolution
        let imgRef = image.cgImage!
        let width: CGFloat = CGFloat(imgRef.width)
        let height: CGFloat = CGFloat(imgRef.height)
        var transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        var bounds = CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height)

        if Int(width) > kMaxResolution || Int(height) > kMaxResolution {
            let ratio: CGFloat = width / height
            if ratio > 1 {
                bounds.size.width = CGFloat(kMaxResolution)
                bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width / ratio
            }
            else {
                bounds.size.height = CGFloat(kMaxResolution)
                bounds.size.width = bounds.size.height * ratio
            }
        }
        let scaleRatio: CGFloat = bounds.size.width / width
        let imageSize = CGSize.init(width: CGFloat(imgRef.width), height: CGFloat(imgRef.height))

        var boundHeight: CGFloat
        let orient = image.imageOrientation
        // The output below is limited by 1 KB.
        // Please Sign Up (Free!) to remove this limitation.

        switch orient {
        case .up:
            //EXIF = 1
            transform = CGAffineTransform.identity
        case .upMirrored:
            //EXIF = 2
            transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: imageSize.width, y: 0.0)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)

        case .down:
            //EXIF = 3
            transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: imageSize.width, y: imageSize.height)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2))

        case .downMirrored:
            //EXIF = 4
            transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: 0.0, y: imageSize.height)
            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: 1.0, y: -1.0)
        case .leftMirrored:
            //EXIF = 5
            boundHeight = bounds.size.height
            bounds.size.height = bounds.size.width
            bounds.size.width = boundHeight
            transform = CGAffineTransform.init(translationX: imageSize.height, y: imageSize.width)

            transform = transform.scaledBy(x: -1.0, y: 1.0)
            transform = transform.rotated(by: CGFloat(Double.pi / 2) / 2.0)
            break

        default: print("Error in processing image")
        }

        UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(bounds.size)
        let context = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()
        if orient == .right || orient == .left {
            context?.scaleBy(x: -scaleRatio, y: scaleRatio)
            context?.translateBy(x: -height, y: 0)
        }
        else {
            context?.scaleBy(x: scaleRatio, y: -scaleRatio)
            context?.translateBy(x: 0, y: -height)
        }
        context?.concatenate(transform)
        context?.draw(imgRef, in: CGRect.init(x: 0, y: 0, width: width, height: height))
        let imageCopy = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()
        return imageCopy!
    }
```